# Solr and JVM memory management issues

Tags: java, memory, solr, jvm

We are facing problem with our Solr deployment running on version 4.6.0 with the following parameters:

```
java -Xss256k -Xms512m -Xmx30g -jar start.jar
```

Solr is running on a Windows Server 2008 R2 with 64GB RAM & 12 cores. 30 GB is allocated to the Solr instance and the size of indexes after data imports are approx. 1.2 GB. 
Upon starting the Solr instance, JVM-memory usage on the Solr dashboard shows:

```
Used Memory: 8.61 GB
Peak Memory: 15.19 GB
Total Memory: 29.02 GB
```

After a few days, we noticed that the memory reads like

```
Used Memory: 22.32 GB
Peak Memory: 29.02 GB
Total Memory: 29.02 GB
```

Index are refreshed every hour (except for between 2am-4am) & their sizes almost never change much.

But, after a little longer, Solr seems to become unresponsive. Solr dashboard doesn’t load and queries fail giving errors like the one below.
We have searched a lot and cannot seem to find any resolution to this. The only interim workaround is to restart Solr instance once java process crosses 30 GB of memory usage. Thereafter it runs well for about 10-12 days but, the same issue again recurs.

And the below given error occurs daily, mostly between 12 am – 6 am. But, there is very less traffic during this time & also no Solr cores are re-indexed between 2am-4am as there is no data change during that period.

We had changed the following couple of configs in jetty.xml but, that also didn’t seem to help much.

```
<Set name="maxIdleTime">1200000</Set>
<Set name="lowResourceMaxIdleTime">10000</Set>
```

```
ERROR - 2015-12-04 02:10:56.821; org.apache.solr.common.SolrException; null:org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException 
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer(HttpGenerator.java:914) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.AbstractGenerator.blockForOutput(AbstractGenerator.java:507) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:147) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:107) 
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(Unknown Source) 
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(Unknown Source) 
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(Unknown Source) 
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(Unknown Source) 
at org.apache.solr.util.FastWriter.flush(FastWriter.java:141) 
at org.apache.solr.util.FastWriter.write(FastWriter.java:55) 
at org.apache.solr.response.JSONWriter.writeStr(JSONResponseWriter.java:449) 
at org.apache.solr.response.JSONWriter.writeKey(JSONResponseWriter.java:103) 
at org.apache.solr.response.JSONWriter.writeSolrDocument(JSONResponseWriter.java:346) 
at org.apache.solr.response.TextResponseWriter.writeDocuments(TextResponseWriter.java:275) 
at org.apache.solr.response.TextResponseWriter.writeVal(TextResponseWriter.java:172) 
at org.apache.solr.response.JSONWriter.writeNamedListAsMapWithDups(JSONResponseWriter.java:183) 
at org.apache.solr.response.JSONWriter.writeNamedList(JSONResponseWriter.java:299) 
at org.apache.solr.response.JSONWriter.writeResponse(JSONResponseWriter.java:95) 
at org.apache.solr.response.JSONResponseWriter.write(JSONResponseWriter.java:60) 
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.writeResponse(SolrDispatchFilter.java:698) 
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:426) 
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:197) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:942) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error 
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) 
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source) 
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ByteArrayBuffer.writeTo(ByteArrayBuffer.java:375) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.bio.StreamEndPoint.flush(StreamEndPoint.java:164) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.bio.StreamEndPoint.flush(StreamEndPoint.java:182) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer(HttpGenerator.java:838)
```

Comment: That was a lot of heap for such a small index. Do you have many millions of tiny documents and a large filterCache? Large slowly filled caches are usually the problem when Solr memory usage continues to grow.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to configure G1GC over ConcurrentMarkSweep for solr, if solr and java version are >5.5 and >1.8.0_5 respectively.

To configure G1GC, follow below parameter

GC_TUNE="-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32m -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=500 -XX:G1NewSizePercent=5 -XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=30 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=45 -XX:G1MixedGCLiveThresholdPercent=65 -XX:+UseLargePages -XX:+AggressiveOpts"

Comment: Basically, limiting the max heap size will help here. InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent can be tuned as per application requirements.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the gradual unresponsiveness can be a symptom of a poorly tuned JVM. I would recommend monitoring the JVM with a tool such as VisualVM with the VisualGC plugin or logging the GC to a file and analyzing it with one of the many available tools.

From the wiki:

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceProblems

> When you have a large heap (larger than 2GB), garbage collection
>   pauses can be a major problem. This is usually caused by occasionally
>   required full garbage collections that must "stop the world" -- pause
>   all program execution to clean up memory. There are two main
>   solutions: One is to use a commercial low-pause JVM like Zing, which
>   does come with a price tag. The other is to tune the free JVM you've
>   already got. GC tuning is an art form, and what works for one person
>   may not work for you.

It's very difficult to know exactly going on unless you get a good look. Considering the size of your heap, you may need to experiment with common parameters such as NewSize or play around with the collection algorithm (ConcurrentMarkSweep can be useful for minimizing pauses for example).

Comment: We've been observing our GC logs closely over the past few days. There doesn't seem to be a direct correlation between GC pauses and Solr becoming unresponsive. The full GC pauses don't always occur at the same time, or in a similar time frame as when Solr becomes unresponsive. 

There are almost no errors from Solr during the day. It becomes unresponsive only at night when neither are there any core indexing jobs, nor are there several hits.

Still trying to find out why JVM's memory utilization is going upto such a high size (upto 30 GB), for total indexes that sizes upto approx 1.5 GB